# Hook for loading proxy presenter (code split)

Tags: gwt-platform

I have a presenter (proxy code split) with method **foo()**. An application was deployed and started. I changed the method signature to **foo(int id)**, stopped the server, deployed the new version of the application and started the server again. When the page with presenter was opened an error occurred because the failed file (generated by gwt compiler and loaded later in situation when proxy code split was used) couldn't be loaded (the names were changed after new compile).

Does anybody know how can I register some code to the situation when a proxy presenter couldn't be loaded?

Kind regards

Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. There are two presenters: Main and NotMain :) NotMain has implemented AsyncCallFailHandler while Main should.